# data modified after send with ajax

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am using javascript and the Flask framework

I would like to retrieve in Flask in python the bytes of one or more files that the user will have chosen in my HTML page. To do this, when the user has chosen the files and has clicked on the send button, it triggers a function that uses the FileReader API to retrieve the base64 content of the file(s) that the user has selected.

After that, I would like to send the base64 data to flask with ajax.

But here is my problem, when I get the base64 string in python and compare it with the one in javascript, I notice the number of characters is exactly the same, but some characters are different as you can see on the screenshots below

[size of character strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFwMn.jpg)

And when I decode the base64 string, I get different bytes :

[bytes variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyzB0.jpg)

This makes me think that the problem is with the use of ajax

Code Python :

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    if request.method == "POST":
        files = eval(request.form.get("files"))
        python_data = file.get("data")
        javascript_data = "" # Copy from chrome console
        len_python_data = len(python_data)
        len_javascript_data = len(javascript_data)
        base64_bytes_javascript = base64.b64decode(javascript_data)
        base64_bytes_python = base64.b64decode(python_data)
```

Code Javascript :

```
let array_files = [];
let files_input = document.getElementById("files_input");
let files = files_input.files;
let reader = new FileReader();
function readFile(index) {
    if( index >= files.length ) {
        let data = "files=" + JSON.stringify(array_files);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/test',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg)
            }
        });
        return;
    }
    let file = files[index];
    reader.name = file.name;
    reader.onload = function() {
        let file_info = {};
        // get file content
        let bin = this.result;
        console.log(bin)
        let data = bin.split(";")[1].replace("base64,", "");
        file_info.name = reader.name;
        file_info.data = data;
        array_files.push(file_info);
        readFile(index + 1)
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
readFile(0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved

In the base64 character string, the "+" were replaced by spaces after sending it to ajax.